# UnitedRPMs For Centos 7

Tags: centos, kdenlive

I'm using Centos 7 and would like to install the latest version of Kdenlive. On their official website, they don't have a repository for Centos, but they do for Fedora which uses UnitedRPMs.

So my question is, is there any way to get UnitedRPMs on Centos 7, and is it safe to do so? I'm also open to any suggestions to get Kdenlive a different way if you happen to use it on Centos 7.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer, the project need some hands...; the UnitedRPMs project, needs maintainers for Centos... The project maintains 4 releases in Fedora (24-27)

Fast solutions

```
1- Use the repository of UnitedRPMs for F24

2- Rebuild the src.rpm of kdenlive ( I recommend with mock)

3- Give your help as maintainer (very hard job)...

4- As sponsor...
```

Comment: Solution 2 sounds good, but I've never done that. How may I attempt that?

Comment: Thank you so much, solution 2 worked like a charm. Building rpm packages with mock: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/05/11/building-rpm-packages-with-mock/